# Date command as a variable in a bash script. Needs to be invoked each time instead of during variable declaration

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script and at certain points I am using echo to put some messages in a log file. The problem that I have is related to the DATE variable which will be static throughout the entire execution of the script.

I have this basic script below to illustrate the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"`

echo "script started at $DATE"

echo "doing something"
sleep 2

echo "script finished at $DATE"
```

If I execute this script, the output of the $DATE variable is the same in both lines. Is there some bash magic that could nicely resolve this without having to replace $DATE with the command itself on each line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: wrap the date command function `fdate() { date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z"; }` then for example `echo "script started at $(fdate)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of the `bash/printf` builtin have support for generating datetime stamps without the need to spawn a subprocess to call `date`:

```
$ builtin printf --help
...snip...
Options:
      -v var    assign the output to shell variable VAR rather than
                display it on the standard output
...snip...
    In addition to the standard format specifications described in printf(1),
    printf interprets:

      %b        expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
      %q        quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
      %(fmt)T   output the date-time string resulting from using FMT as a format
                string for strftime(3)
... snip ...
```

Instead of spawning a subprocess to call `date`, eg:

```
logdt=`date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%z"`
```

The same can be accomplished via `printf -v` by wrapping the desired format in `%(...)T`, eg:

```
printf -v logdt '%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%z)T'
```

**NOTE:** assuming `%:z` should be `:%z`

Assuming you'll be tagging a lot of lines with datetime stamps then the savings from eliminating the subproces `date` calls could be huge.

Running a test of 1000 datetime stamp generations:

```
$ time for ((i=1;i<=1000;i++)); do { printf -v logdt '%(...)T' | logdate=$(date ...) }; done
```

Timings for `printf -v logdt '%(...)T'`:

```
real    0m0.182s              # ~130 times faster than $(date ...)
user    0m0.171s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Timings for `logdt=$(date ...)`:

```
real    0m24.443s             # ~130 times slower than printf -v 
user    0m5.533s
sys     0m16.724s
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash version 4.3+ , you can use the builtin `printf` to format datetimes. `-1` below is a magic value that means "now".

```sh
#!/bin/bash

datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

printf "script started at %($datefmt)T\n" -1

echo "doing something"
sleep 2

printf "script finished at %($datefmt)T\n" -1
```

bash didn't recognize `%:z` for me.

Comment: Glenn, do you know if it can format a Zulu time (timezone Z) rather than local time? I searched but could not find.

Comment: Anwsered my own: `TZ= printf '%(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)T %s\n' -1 'This is a UTC Zulu timestamped message'`

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "script started at $(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z')"

echo "doing something"
sleep 2

echo "script finished at $(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z')"
```

You might want to create an alias if calling the full command looks clumsy to you.

Comment: Alases don't work in scripts, but a function would. Functions are basically superior to aliases in every other aspect, too.